# why the data of userform always goes to the same row?

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, when I input the data in the userform all the information appears but it is always in the same row it doesn't go to the next empty row. I'm trying to input the data into my excel file and keep adding the information to the next empty row.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim emptyRow As Long

    'Make Sheet1 active
    Sheet1.Activate

    'Determine emptyRow
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

    'values need to be enter in order to move on
    If ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
        Cancel = 1
        MsgBox "Please enter the part line "
        ComboBox1.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If ComboBox4.Value = "" Then
        Cancel = 1
        MsgBox "Please enter a part description"
        ComboBox4.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If TextBox3.Value = "" Then
        Cancel = 1
        MsgBox "Please enter a part quantity"
        TextBox3.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If ComboBox2.Value = "" Then
        Cancel = 1
        MsgBox "Please enter a part finish"
        ComboBox2.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Transfer information

    Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = ComboBox1.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TextBox1.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = ComboBox4.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = TextBox3.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = ComboBox2.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = DTPicker1.Value


    ComboBox1.Value = Null
    ComboBox4.Value = Null
    TextBox3.Value = Null
    ComboBox2.Value = Null

End Sub
```

Comment: Try with "yourworksheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row" instead of WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

Answer (score 0):

You will want to get the next empty row like this instead:

```
emptyRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: i try that and now the data is being place in the last row row all the time and not on the empty row that is on the bottom.